# Missing python.h when trying to install Apache Thrift

Tags: server, apt, apache2

I have tried many times over to install Thrift (http://thrift.apache.org/) in Ubuntu Server. I tried it on two machines... And one I had nothing on it before; meaning fresh Ubuntu installation.

I did: `./configure`, no problems here.

But then if I run `make`, everything stops working:

```
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/protocol
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c src/protocol/fastbinary.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/src/protocol/fastbinary.o
src/protocol/fastbinary.c:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make[3]: *** [all-local] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift-0.6.0/lib/py'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift-0.6.0/lib'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/thrift-0.6.0'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I try to install Python; I get:

```
apt-get install python2.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python2.6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I have been search everywhere for an answer, but nothing. I am I the only one running into this problem? Is there a solution that exists? I am not sure I feel my legs anymore :\

Also, I tried to install `php-dev` but I get an error:

```
E: Unable to locate package php-dev
```

I was able to install: `php5-dev`, is there a difference?

Any help would be great thanks :|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot install Python modules](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247845/i-cannot-install-python-modules)

Comment: This question is older.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install python dev

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```