# Python.h: No such file or directory #include <Python.h>

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt

When trying to compile pyqt i have an error [image: error of the python.h]

i have installed all the prerequistes but its still showing the same problem please find an answer for this

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942887/how-to-configure-pyqt4-for-python-3-in-ubuntu

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I cannot install Python modules](http://askubuntu.com/questions/247845/i-cannot-install-python-modules)

Answer (score 3):

For Python 2

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Since `Python.h` is provided by `-dev`

For Python 3

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

the missing header file Python.h is in the python-dev package, first check that you have it installed:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections |grep python-dev
libboost-mpi-python-dev             install
libboost-python-dev             install
python-dev                  install
```

You can also use 'locate' to see if the file exists:

```
$ locate Python.h
/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h
```

Once you know that you have the header file, try to see where the compiler is looking for it:

```
cd PyQt_installation_dir
grep -r python2.7 .
...
./QtNetwork/QtNetwork.pro:INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/python2.7
...
```

In my case the problem was that the file was in /usr/include/python2.7, but the Makefile include path (-I) contained /usr/local/include/python2.7. To work around this, I made a link:

```
cd /usr/local/include
ln -s ../../include/python2.7 .
```

Maybe there is a nicer way to do this, but at least the compilation worked.

Best,
Harri